# как сделать так чтобы график продолжался при методе наименьших квадратов на python

Tags: python, математика, matplotlib

смотрите,есть такой код,ось перестает чертится когда заканчивается матрица,как сделать так чтобы линия продолжала предугадывать значения

```
x_train = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y_train = np.array([1.1,3.8,6.5,10.2,13.1])

A = np.vstack([x_train**2, x_train, np.ones(len(x_train))]).T
a, b, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y_train, rcond=None)[0]
y_sel = np.array([a*x**2 + b*x + c for x in x_train])
print(f"Полученная парабола: {a}x^2 + {b}x + {c}")
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train)
plt.plot(x_train, y_sel, color='red')
plt.xlim([-45, 45])
plt.ylim([0, 75])
plt.ylabel("длина")
plt.xlabel("ширина")
plt.grid(True)
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
plt.show()
```

вот график
[image: график]

а должен так

[image: график]

пожалуйста помогите,буду очень благодарен

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296603/extrapolation-from-data-plotted-using-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

Ну вы же получили коэффициенты для формулы и прямо сама формула у вас уже есть. Осталось вычислить `y` на тех `x`, которых у вас ещё нет. Вернее, чтобы линия была непрерывной, начинать нужно с последней точки `x`, которую вы уже рисовали, т.е. с `5`:

```py
x_pred = np.arange(5, 14)
# y_pred = np.array([a*x**2 + b*x + c for x in x_pred])
# запишем эту формулу, которая у вас есть в коде, проще/короче
y_pred = a*x_pred**2 + b*x_pred + c
plt.plot(x_pred, y_pred, color='blue')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]